# Why are my pandas DataFrame columns Dataframes too, not Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Update at end**
**Update 2 at end**

I read from here:
[get list from pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column)

> Pandas DataFrame columns are Pandas Series when you pull them out

However this is not true in my case:

First part (building up the DataFrame reading json scraped)
Because it contains business info I cannot show the full code, but basically it reads one row of data (stored in Series) and append at the end of the DataFrame.

```
dfToWrite = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[lsHeader]) # Empty with column headers
for row in jsAdtoolJSON['rows']:
    lsRow = []
    for col in row['row']:
        lsRow.append((col['primary'])['value'])
    dfRow = pandas.Series(lsRow, index = dfToWrite.columns)
dfToWrite = dfToWrite.append(dfRow, ignore_index = True)
```

Next part (check type): (Please ignore the functionality of the function)

```
def CalcMA(df: pandas.DataFrame, target: str, period: int, maname: str):
    print(type(df[target]))
```

Finally call the function: ("Raw_Impressions" is a column header)

```
CalcMA(dfToWrite, "Raw_Impressions", 5, "ImpMA5")
```

Python console shows:

> class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

**Additional Question**: How to get a list from a Dataframe column if it's not a Series (in which case I can use `tolist()`)?

**Update 1**
From here:
[Bokeh: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316088/bokeh-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-tolist)

I figured out that I need to use `.value.tolist()`, however it still doesn't explain why I'm getting another Dataframe, not a Series when I pull out a column.

**Update 2**
Found out that df has MultiIndex, very surprised:

> MultiIndex(levels=[['COST_/*CPM', 'CTR', 'ECPM*/_ROI', 'Goal_Ratio', 'Hour_of_the_Day', 'IMP./Joins', 'Raw_Clicks_/_Unique_Clicks', 'Raw_Impressions', 'Unique_Goal_/_UniqueGoal_Forecasted_Value']],
>              labels=[[4, 7, 5, 6, 1, 8, 3, 0, 2]])

I don't see the `labels` when printing out the df / writing to .csv, it's just a normal DataFrame. Not sure where did I get the labels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have duplicated columns names, so if want select `Series` get `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[4,5], [7,8]], index=list('aab')).T
print (df)
   a  a  b
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8

print (df['a'])
   a  a
0  1  4
1  2  5

print (type(df['a']))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df['b'])
0    7
1    8
Name: b, dtype: int64

print (type(df['b']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

EDIT:

Here is another problem, one level `MultiIndex`, solution is reassign first level back to columns with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex([['COST_/CPM', 'CTR', 'ECPM/_ROI', 'Goal_Ratio', 'Hour_of_the_Day', 
                      'IMP./Joins',  'Raw_Clicks_/_Unique_Clicks', 'Raw_Impressions',
                      'Unique_Goal_/_UniqueGoal_Forecasted_Value']], 
labels=[[4, 7, 5, 6, 1, 8, 3, 0, 2]])

df = pd.DataFrame([range(9)], columns=mux)
print (type(df['CTR']))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
print (type(df['CTR']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, just printed out the columns and found out that actually I have a MultiIndex, does it cause the issue? (The `levels` do not have duplicates) It's very strange, because when I `print(df)` it doesn't show any of the labels. I'll update the question with labels.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey - yes, if MultiIndex then it means duplicated first level :)

Comment: thanks, finally found the source of the problem. BTW I should not have MultiIndex so I'll figure out a way to find the source of that.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey - Added solution for your situtation.

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look in the morning but I think it will work. Now next step is to track down the source of MultiIndex...

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey - yes, this kind of error is very unpleasent, especially because not seen if print DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` is basically an array so if you are getting this type you can get each column ( which if the column is 1 dimensional will be of type `pandas.core.series.Series` ) by calling `df.columns`.

`df.columns` will give you an iterable object that you can loop through to get your values along each row.

You might also want to look at `pandas.read_json` or other similar package just to get the `json` directly into a pandas object which might be easier to manage

Comment: Thanks @NiallJG I managed to use `df(target).values.tolist()` to get a list from a column. But it still confuses me why `df(target)`, in which `target` is just a string, does not represent a `Series`

Comment: @jezrael 's answer suggests that maybe there are duplicate columns, try running print(df.columns)  and see what the column headings are named, maybe there are two of the same string

Comment: thanks yeah I found out there is multiindex, I'll check the previous code to find the source of that.